# How to get user's name on Sign in with Apple?

Tags: jwt, apple-sign-in, apple-login

I'm trying to authenticate users with Apple *on the web* (which is required as we also have an iOS app and have a Login with Facebook option and we have to bring Sign in with Apple too otherwise Apple rejects our app updates on iOS side) and here is my meta tags (with sensitive info redacted) as in Apple's example:

```
<meta name="appleid-signin-client-id" content="com.myapp">
<meta name="appleid-signin-scope" content="name email">
<meta name="appleid-signin-redirect-uri" content="https://my.return.url">
<meta name="appleid-signin-state" content="x login">
<meta name="appleid-signin-nonce" content="some number">
<meta name="appleid-signin-use-popup" content="false">
```

When the user taps the button it asks for sharing a name and/or email correctly:

[image]

I proceed, and my redirect URL is called as expected. However, when I decode the returned `id_token` I see only `email` and `email_verified` fields in addition to the JWT-related fields. I don't have anything related to the user's name. I know that the name field is populated only on the first auth so this is after a fresh login after removing my app from my Apple ID from the "Apps & Websites using Apple ID" page. If I change `appleid-signin-scope` on meta tags to `name` I don't get an email either, so that value is *somehow* being respected. I also haven't touched anything regarding the name field as in the screenshot (I could proceed by Touch ID without even clicking anything) yet the `id_token` can only have email, not name. I need to get users' names in addition to email in order to finish registration, and *I'm forced to* add Sign-in with the Apple option to push any updates to my iOS app. Many people have reported that they get the name only the first time (as clearly stated by Apple), but I'm not getting it even on the first time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it perhaps a security feature - the user signing in with their apple ID would assume only their apple ID is shared with you??

Comment: @MrR nope. it presents a screen that i can explicitly enable/disable sharing name/real mail. i'm testing with my own account and i'm granting the permission.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it seems this isn't possible. However the name is returned as JSON in the response body from the "authorization" endpoint along with the id token. This is only available the first time a user signs in, when they give consent for your application to access their name and email address, not on subsequent sign-ins.

[Apple documentation - Retrieve the User’s Information](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple#3383773)

> If you request the user’s full name, Sign in with Apple collects the information to pass along to your app. The name defaults to the user’s name from their Apple ID, but the user can change their name. **The modified name is only shared with your app and not with Apple, and hence isn’t included in the ID token.**

Response from "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize" including "user" object:

```
{
  "code": "AUTH_CODE",
  "id_token": "ID_TOKEN",
  "user": {
    "name": {
      "firstName": "Jeb",
      "lastName": "Kerman"
    },
    "email": "jeb.kerman@apple.com"
  }
}
```

[Apple documentation - Handle authorization Response](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms#3332115)

Answer (score -1):

The code needs to request the `UserI` property, as specified in the [Sign in with Apple API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/useri) documentation.

**Sample:**

```
<meta name="appleid-signin-client-id" content="com.myapp">
<meta name="appleid-signin-scope" content="UserI">
<meta name="appleid-signin-redirect-uri" content="https://my.return.url">
<meta name="appleid-signin-state" content="x login">
<meta name="appleid-signin-nonce" content="some number">
<meta name="appleid-signin-use-popup" content="false">
```

[image: Image of documentation]

Comment: From where exactly did you get that the HTML tag's content should be set to the literal "UserI"? I didn't see it in the docs at the link. UserI is an interface, there is no notion of the interface name "UserI" being used as a string literal at the HTML tag.

Comment: I read the docs. It's a signin scope value.

Comment: is there a link to where it specifies this kind of usage? it's _not_ at the link at the answer.

Comment: I thought it was. I added an image to the answer showing it.

Comment: I've seen that page, but there's no notion of using `UserI` as a literal string value. it's not a string, it's an interface name.

Comment: @9pfs please remove this comment and only comment if you know what you're saying. The OP has noted that this isn't a valid response, and asking them to just try it out isn't helpful.